# Is there a Javascript function to make the code delay at the point that code run?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I got this `<button onclick="alert('1');setInterval(function(){},57000);alert('2');"> Show </button>`

The delay didn't work.

`setTimeout` also didn't work.

**How to fix it?**

Comment: `function(){} ` <-- but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [time delay between 2 lines of code in javascript, not settimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048724/time-delay-between-2-lines-of-code-in-javascript-not-settimeout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the alert inside the `setInterval` callback:

```
<button onclick="alert('1');setInterval(function(){alert('2');},57000);"> Show </button>
```

---

Simple extended version of your code:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

function myFunction(){
  div.textContent += '-'; 
  // beware, this code might crash your browser if left running
  // for a few (thousand) years!!!
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setInterval(myFunction, 1000);"> Start Interval </button>
<div></div>
```

---

A properly styled version of the code above:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('d');
var button = document.getElementById('b');

button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

function myFunction(){
  div.textContent += '-'; 
  // beware, this code might crash your browser if left running
  // for a few (thousand) years!!!
}

function clickHandler(){
  setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button id="b"> Start Interval </button>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way not to do it. Let make the code seperated

Comment: You can put all the other code inside a function, then just pass that function as a parameter to `setInterval`: `setInterval(myFunction, 57000);`

Comment: Note that this would alert "2" every 57 seconds. Nothing against the answer, just for those looking for a delay rather than an repeating call.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, yeah, I think OP is aware of the difference between intervals and timeouts, at least it seems so from the question.

Comment: Can myFuntion(){x=1;}; ok?

Comment: Sure, you can put whatever you want in that function and you can name it however you want. I'm just showing you the principle.

Comment: The problem is myFuntion(){x=1;}; finish so quickly so 500 or 500000 milliseconds are no different? Do you have a delayFunction that does not make it crash?

Comment: You're not doing something right then. For a one-time delay use `setTimeout` like you originally tried.

Comment: alert('1'); setTimeout(delayFunction(),29000); alert('2'); will not work if delayFunction only has x=1; since it can run x=1 so quickly

Comment: Because you're calling the function, you need only to pass the function body as I wrote in my answer: `setTimeout(delayFunction,29000);` (note the brackets)

Comment: Seem Div.textContent  doesn't worjk int my browser? other simpler way?

Comment: I can't know without seeing the code, you probably have an error.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById('d');
function delayFunction(){
  div.textContent += '-'; 
  // beware, this code might crash your browser if left running
  // for a few (thousand) years!!!
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d"></div>

<button onclick="setTimeout(delayFunction(),3000);alert('2');setTimeout(delayFunction(),3000);alert('2');"> run </button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you copy that above code & run? it didn't work at all

Comment: Try jsfiddle to create the error. No need to keep my comments, see the dev console for errors.

Comment: Read the console, you didn't assign the id to the button: https://jsfiddle.net/8bbwb3Lq/3/

Comment: the problem is that your code does not take the the delayTIme in **button onclick="setInterval(delayFunction(),3000);alert('2');setInterval(delayFunction(),3000);alert('2');"> run **; it only take the delayTIme in handler. and that does not meet the requirement

Comment: I have no requirements, and I didn't write how `setInterval` works. I've just shown you how to use it by answering your question. It will never work the way you described it.

Answer (score 0):

- **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bbwb3Lq/)**

JavaScript code runs *synchronously*, which means that each instruction is executed one after another. Let's take a look at your code:

```
alert('1');

setInterval(function(){
    //does nothing
}, 57000);

alert('2');
```

Now each line will execute one after the other, which means `alert(1)` will execute, then `setInterval(...)` and then `alert(2)`. Your `setInterval` doesn't *stop* the other lines from executing.

If you want to have a delay on your code execution, you must consider having that code execute *after* your `setInterval` (I'm assuming you want to use `setTimeout` here) finishes.

Also, as a pro-top, you should separate your JavaScript code from your HTML. Let's consider the following:

```
<button id="myButton">Show</button>
...
<script>
// Get a reference to your button
var myButton = document.querySelector('#myButton');

// The code you want to execute after the given time
function executeLater(){
    alert(2);
}

// We attach an event listener to your button
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('1');
    setTimeout(executeLater, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: what if you don't put alert('2') inside the myFunction?, if you do that it won't delay

Comment: @Tum You must understand the synchronicity of JavaScript - simply having a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` alone will not block the code after it, so if you want code to execute at a later time you must use a callback